# REST API enabled products not displaying on front-end

Tags: product, api, frontend, rest-api

When loading products via REST API(Oauth) they don't display on the front-end. The status is enabled(1) en inventory(stock_data) is set correct.  We have to manually change status per product and save via admin back-end. Even bulk status change via admin back-end does not work.

What could be the cause of this and how can we fix it?

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 and PHP Version 5.4.21

Comment: do you set the visibility attribute?

Comment: Yes I do to Catalog, Search(4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it had to do with the website_id and not the status. When creating, editing and saving a product via admin back-end website_id is set automatically, but when creating via REST API website_id is not set. Had to POST website_id 1 via REST API.

Kind of strange behavior would think it should default to main website_id and the POST website_id is for adding to additional and updating.